TabView child views don't support ToolbarItem and NavigationTitle
I have some issues with child views inside TabView.
This is my parent view:
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TabView {
               OverviewView()
                   .tabItem { Label("Overview", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle")}               
               BillsView()
                   .tabItem { Label("Bills", systemImage: "newspaper")}                        
               CompaniesView()
                   .tabItem { Label("Companies", systemImage: "building")} 
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(location.name)
    }
}

This works as I can switch through the views and the navigationTitle is location.name for all tab item child views. However If I want to add .toolbar { ToolbarItem } within any of the views it just doesn't show. Also I can't add the navigationTitle for each view. Two navigationTitles would probably be a no-go so what would be the best approach to have a title for each child view below the prominent navigationTitle?
Here is the code for one of the child views (ToolbarItem and NavigationTitle don't show at all):
var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
       List {
           ...    
       }.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem {
                NavigationLink("Add") {
                    AddBillView()
                }
            }
        }.navigationTitle("Bills View")
    }
}

One approach that works is to use NavigationBarItems to add a button that would open a sheet with the AddBillView() but I would like to do it via ToolbarItem if possible.
Is this a limitation in SwiftUI or am I doing something wrong? Thanks.

So if you want a navstack for the child view then you would need to have it in the child view. currently you have the tabview inside the navstack when what you want is the tabview with the individual tabs and inside each tab they have their own navstacks. maybe something like:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
           OverviewView()
           .tabItem { Label("Overview", systemImage: "list.bullet.rectangle") }

           BillsView()
           .tabItem { Label("Bills", systemImage: "newspaper") }

           CompaniesView()
           .tabItem { Label("Companies", systemImage: "building") }
        }
    }
}

struct BillsView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("Bills View")
            }
           .navigationTitle("Bills")
           .toolbar { 
               ToolbarItem {
                   NavigationLink("Add") {
                       AddBillsView()
                   }
               }
           }
        }
    }
}

struct OverviewView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("OverviewView")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Overview")
            .toolbar { /* add your toolbar items here */ }
        }
    }
}

struct CompaniesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Text("CompaniesView")
            }
            .navigationTitle("Companies")
            .toolbar { /* add your toolbar items here */ }
        }
    }
}



I've removed NavStack from the parent and included it in the child as you've specified but it still does not work. I even simplified and used your exact code to test it but it doesn't show neither title or toolbarItem

I added a screenshot that correspond to the example code i provided you. Here "Bills" is the navigation title and ToolBarItem is added only inside BillsView. Is there a screenshot of your desired behaviour?
